# call a twig function (render) with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have in my template a twig call :

```
{{ render(controller( 'MyApplicationBundle:Application:timeline', { 'number': '0-10' } )) }}
```

So, with this line, i call my action `timeline`, retrieve the last 10 posts of my timeline, call my view `timeline.html.twig` and display them.

I need, when the user scroll to the bottom of the page for example, re-call this line and change the parameter number (with 10-20) for retrieve other posts and re-display them.

My question, how can i call this line `(render(controller)))` with ajax and display the response on my page ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to call render(controller) from js? You can simply call `MyApplicationBundle:Application:timeline` by his url? What the problem?

Comment: Because i want to, when the user scroll to bottom of the page, recall the same controller with an other parameter, for display other post..